# How should I adapt my continuous model to the discrete data records?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $N(t) :N \in \mathbb{N}, t \in \mathbb{R}$ a stochastic jumping process over the time. $N(t)$ is characterized by a unknown **pmf (probability mass function)** and represents the number of jumps happened in the interval $[0, t]$. On other hand, the time $t$ between a jump $N_i$ and the next one $N_{i+1}$ is random an characterized by unknown **pdf (probability density function)**.

I wanted to find out such *pmf* for jumps and *pdf* for time but I came across the next problem. The time is recorded in *minute-by-minute* way, so I don't know how it affects to my model. Should I assume that time ($t$) belongs to real $\mathbb{R}$ or natural $\mathbb{N}$ numbers? How should I face this issue? Should I change my model?

Just for adding information, 80% of data time is between 0 and 50 minutes, the other 19% between 50 and 150, and the other 1% are outliers and rare times.

Comment: I feel I would need much more information to give a definitive reply. Nevertheless, I though about Poisson processes and exponential times while reading your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not include more information because what I only want to know is if I should change the model given that the time is collected minute-by-minute. If I assume the time continuous, I would try to fit it with a pdf  (e.g the exponential distribution) If I assume the time is discrete, I would try to fit with a pmf (in such case I would not know what to do)